# Copying tag-wiki text from SO to SF is it (citation needed)?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

We've had a couple of users figure out that they can get rep by copying tag wikis from SO into SF. While completion is nice, I believe they need attribution for where the original text come from. Is this approvable behavior?

Comment: I think it would only clutter the tag wiki, just fill it them up already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they contributed the content on SO, they own the rights to it so I don't see the problem squeezing a measly extra 2 reputation out of it.

If they didn't, they must comply with the [license attribution requirements](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). This can only happen for the tag wiki body, not the tag wiki excerpt (no links allowed) — and even then not fully, given that users can't change the `ref="nofollow"` attribute.